# Jordan Lemma - Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

How does the all of the LHS equal zero?

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{H_R} \frac{e^{imz}\,dz}{a^2 + z^2}=0$$

Please see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThwpD.png) for more full question and context.

Comment: You should specify what the countour $H_R$ is.

Comment: Assuming $H_R$ denotes the arc spanning the real axis of radius R, the limit of the integral is $0$ as $R$ tends to infinity because $|zf(z)|$ goes to $0$ as $|z|$ goes to infinity, where $f$ denotes the integrand. (Notice that in the upper plane, the imaginary part of $z$ is positive, so if $m>0$, which seems to be the case according to your link, the exponential does not explode)

Comment: Okay we're making progress. Still have a couple question from your comment Evariste. (1) - how is the limit 0 when R tends to inifinity?  (2)- How do you know |z| goes to inifity? (3)- How does |zf(z)| end up going to 0?

Comment: @Evariste : I would call $H_R$  the (unclosed) upper semi-circle of radius $R$

Comment: have a look may be at http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~jdg/eejordan.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly with the ML inequality, for $\;m>0\;$? :

$$\left|\int_{H_R}\frac{e^{imz}}{z^2+a^2}dz\right|\le\ell(H_R)\max_{z\in H_R}\frac{|e{^{imz}|}}{|z^2+a^2|}\le\pi R\frac{e^{-m\,\text{Im}\,z}}{R^2-a^2}\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

since Im$\,z>0\;$ for $\;z\in H_R\;$

Answer (score 0):

Let $m>0$

**Proposition :**

Assuming $H_R$ denotes the arc spanning the real axis of radius $R$, the limit of the integral is $0$ as $R$ tends to infinity because $|zf(z)|$ goes to $0$ as $|z|$ goes to infinity, where $f$ denotes the integrand.

**Proof :**

Intuitively speaking, $|z|$ is the distance of the point $(x,y)$ to the origin $(0,0)$ in the complex plane.
In a more formal way, if $z=x+iy$, then $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

As the semi-circle radius grows to infinity, the distance of one of its points relative to the origin grows to infinity to. Indeed, the semi-circle of radius R in the upper plane is just :

{$z=Re^{i\theta},\theta \in ]0,\pi[$}

and $|Re^{i\theta}|=R$.

So as $R$ grows and tends to infinity, $|z|$ tends to infinity too.

We are interested in

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{H_R} \frac{e^{imz}\,dz}{a^2 + z^2}$$

First, notice that

$$|\int_{H_R} \frac{e^{imz}\,dz}{a^2 + z^2}|=|\int_{H_R} f(z)dz|=|\int_{H_R} zf(z)\frac{dz}{z}|$$

Since $z=Re^{i\theta}$, with R constant because we are integrating $z$ over a semi-circle, $dz=Rd(e^{i\theta})=Rie^{i\theta}d\theta=izd\theta$

So

$$|\int_{H_R} zf(z)\frac{dz}{z}|=|\int_{0}^{\pi} zf(z)id\theta|=|\int_{0}^{\pi} zf(z)d\theta|\times|i|=|\int_{0}^{\pi} zf(z)d\theta|\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} |zf(z)|d\theta \leq \pi sup(|zf(z)|)$$

However, $|zf(z)|=\frac{|z|}{|z^2+a^2|} \times |e^{imz}|$

We have

$lim _{|z| \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|z|}{|z^2+a^2|}=0$ because the denominator clearly dominates the numerator

and if $z=x+iy$, we must have $y>0$ because the semi-circle is located in the upper plane, so :

$|e^{imz}|=|e^{imx-my}|=e^{-my} \times |e^{imx}|=e^{-my}$

so $lim_{|z| \rightarrow +\infty}|e^{imz}|=lim_{y \rightarrow +\infty}e^{-my}=0$

Note that this trick wouldn't have worked in the lower half plane, since $y$ would have been negative and the minus sign in the exponential would become a plus sign, making the limit explode to infinity.

As a result,

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} |\int_{H_R} \frac{e^{imz}\,dz}{a^2 + z^2}| \leq \pi\times lim_{|z| \rightarrow +\infty} sup(|zf(z)|)=0$$

So $$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{H_R} \frac{e^{imz}\,dz}{a^2 + z^2}=0$$

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. First question, what does sup(|zf(z)|) mean? Secondly just by inspection how would you if the complex integral would go to zero with having to go through the proof: Should I just me looking out for the denominator dominating?

Comment: Sup is the biggest value the argument can take or tend to.  I don't know at which University you're studying, but in most situations, unless asked otherwise, you don't need to go through the proof time and again if it's an arc. Just notice that $|zf(z)|$ goes to $0$. However, don't limit yourself to looking at the fraction, as in some cases, the exponential can explode and $|zf(z)|$ won't go to zero.